# Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.BeginSignIn Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, sdk, skype, lync, skypedeveloper

I'm using Lync Client to SignIn account:

```
_LyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient(true);
if (_LyncClient == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Unable to obtain client interface");
}

_LyncClient.SignInDelayed += _LyncClient_SignInDelayed;
_LyncClient.StateChanged += _LyncClient_StateChanged;
_LyncClient.CredentialRequested += _LyncClient_CredentialRequested;

......

try
{     
    if (_LyncClient.State == ClientState.SignedIn)
    {
        _LyncClient.BeginSignOut(
            ar =>
            {
                //Set a class field flag so that the application 
                //shuts down the Lync platform when the application closes
                _LyncClient.EndInitialize(ar);
            },
            null);
    }

    if (_LyncClient.State == ClientState.Uninitialized)
    {
        _LyncClient.BeginInitialize(
            ar =>
            {
                //Set a class field flag so that the application 
                //shuts down the Lync platform when the application closes
                _LyncClient.EndInitialize(ar);
                //_LyncClient.StateChanged += _LyncClient_StateChanged;
            },
            null);
    }

    if (_LyncClient.State == ClientState.SignedOut)
    {
        if (_callback != null)
            _callback.OnSignInStart();

        _LyncClient.BeginSignIn(
            this.email,
            upnOrDomainUserName,
            password,
            ar =>
            {
                _LyncClient.EndSignIn(ar);
                if (_callback != null)
                {
                    _callback.OnSignInSuccess();
                }
            },
            null);
    }
}
catch (NotStartedByUserException h)
{
    throw new Exception("Lync is not running: " + h);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("General Exception: " + ex);
}
```

However, this code generates the exception:

```
    General Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. at Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.BeginSignIn(String userUri, String domainAndUsername, String password, AsyncCallback communicatorClientCallback, Object state)
```

What can cause this? I could not find any information from search. The code is running as Windows Service.

Thanks

Comment: Is the service running as `System` or a real user account?

Comment: tried both cases. same issue.

Comment: Did you check `Event Viewer`?

Comment: yes, but nothing related

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick Google search also and your issue may be an environment issue. See same error [here](https://infrastructurehelp.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/certificate-status-missing-in-lync/).

Comment: i'm sorry, but is the link correct? seems a different error.

Comment: If you do a ctrl + f for "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." you should find it.

Comment: that's the same, but it has no relation with  Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.BeginSignIn